# Trying to add custom fields to envelope definition from docusign rails example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I got the embedded signing method I got from rails example on how to implement docusign embedded signing into your rails app.

I added a custom_fields object and added to the envelope object I created from the example

```
def embedded_signing
    # base_url is the url of this application. Eg http://localhost:3000
    base_url = request.base_url
    user = HiringManager.find params[:hiring_manager_id]
    # Fill in these constants
    # Obtain an OAuth token from https://developers.hqtest.tst/oauth-token-generator

    access_token = Token.access_token

    # Obtain your accountId from demo.docusign.com -- the account id is shown in the drop down on the
    # upper right corner of the screen by your picture or the default picture.
    account_id = ENV["docusign_client_id"]

    # Recipient Information:
    signer_name = user.full_name 
    signer_email = user.email

    base_path = 'http://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
    client_user_id = user.id # Used to indicate that the signer will use an embedded
    # Signing Ceremony. Represents the signer's userId within
    # your application.
    authentication_method = 'None' # How is this application authenticating
    # the signer? See the `authenticationMethod' definition
    file_name = 'agreement.pdf' # The document to be signed.

    # Step 1. Create the envelope request definition
    envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new
    envelope_definition.email_subject = "Please sign this Newcraft Placement Agreement"

    doc = DocuSign_eSign::Document.new({
      :documentBase64 => Base64.encode64(File.binread(File.join('data', file_name))),
      :name => "Agreement signed", :fileExtension => "pdf", :documentId => "1"})

    # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
    envelope_definition.documents = [doc]
    # create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
    # We're setting the parameters via the object creation
    signer = DocuSign_eSign::Signer.new ({
        :email => signer_email, :name => signer_name,
        :clientUserId => client_user_id,  :recipientId => 1
    })
    sign_here = DocuSign_eSign::SignHere.new ({
        :documentId => '1', :pageNumber => '4',
        :recipientId => '1', :tabLabel => 'SignHereTab',
        :xPosition => '75', :yPosition => '70'
    })

    # Tabs are set per recipient / signer
    tabs = DocuSign_eSign::Tabs.new({:signHereTabs => [sign_here]})

    signer.tabs = tabs
    # Add the recipients to the envelope object
    recipients = DocuSign_eSign::Recipients.new({:signers => [signer]})

    envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
    # Add custom fields to the envelope object
    custom_fields = DocuSign_eSign::CustomFieldV2.new({
        :configuration_type => 'text', :required => 'true',
        :name => 'date', :fieldId => '', :value => 'Todays date'
    })

    envelope_definition.custom_fields = custom_fields
    # Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
    # To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
    envelope_definition.status = "sent"

    # Step 2. Call DocuSign with the envelope definition to have the
    #         envelope created and sent
    configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
    configuration.host = base_path
    api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new configuration
    api_client.default_headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + access_token
    envelopes_api = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new api_client

    results = envelopes_api.create_envelope account_id, envelope_definition
    envelope_id = results.envelope_id

    # Step 3. create the recipient view request for the Signing Ceremony
    view_request =  DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest.new
    # Set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
    # should typically be a callback route somewhere in your app.
    view_request.return_url = "https://juice.newcraft.io/edit-manager"
    # How has your app authenticated the user? In addition to your app's
    # authentication, you can include authenticate steps from DocuSign.
    # Eg, SMS authentication
    view_request.authentication_method = authentication_method
    # Recipient information must match embedded recipient info
    # we used to create the envelope.
    view_request.email = signer_email
    view_request.user_name = signer_name
    view_request.client_user_id = client_user_id

    # Step 4. call the CreateRecipientView API
    results = envelopes_api.create_recipient_view account_id, envelope_id, view_request

    user.signed_agreement = true 
    user.save

    # Step 5. Redirect the user to the Signing Ceremony
    # Don't use an iFrame!
    # State can be stored/recovered using the framework's session or a
    # query parameter on the returnUrl (see the makeRecipientViewRequest method)
    render json: results

  rescue DocuSign_eSign::ApiError => e
    @error_msg = e.response_body
    render json: @error_msg
  end
```

I am finding it difficult understanding how to insert a custom field that user can manually fill on the pdf agreement document that is displayed for users signature. I also know I need to add the position the custom field tab will reside which the documentation does not really explain how to add to an envelop object you create from a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's try to see if we understand your requirement. You want user to fill in some data on the envelope and then collect this data in your application after the envelope is complete, is that correct?
To do that, you don't need custom fields. You can easily to that with regular tabs. Text tabs are probably the simplest way to do so. You add a text tab to your envelope, similar to how you added a SignHere tab and the user would have to fill in the text/value. You can then get this information using other API calls. 
Here is the API call to obtain the tab value:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/
You basically do a GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs if you are using the v2 or V2.1 API (just replace 2.1 with 2)

Comment: thanks what method do i use to add the envelope recipient tab?. you made reference to signhere which is called using the method "SignHere.new" for example

Comment: I think you mean to ask about the text tab, right?
"DocuSign_eSign::Text.new" is how you generate it in Ruby. See a fuller example code in here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-create-template (change to Ruby)

Comment: You we welcome, do you mind marking this response as an answer? that would help make it more useful for others. Appreciate i!